# Issue facing when trying to fix the navigation bar at the top when user scrolls the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix the navigation bar at the top when user scrolls the page. But i am facing some problem with it. While doing so i found that some elements overlaps over it i.e it hides the navigation bar and displays itself over it.

Say i have a nav bar of background-color blue and a div somewhere down with background color yellow. When i scroll down to that div it overlaps the nav and hide the blue color of nav bar and shows yellow color..

Any help regarding this would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: If you want someone to be able to help you, you should at least provide relevant code in question... Have you try to set z-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you want to set the position: absolute and the z-index.
without your code cant give you are specific answer but this should get you in the right direction

Comment: Appreciate your help i got it correct by setting the z-index :1

Comment: @user3644860 no problem, glad you got it working. may want to set the z-index on that one to something larger, 100 or something so it wont get overlapped often unless you intentionally do it

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a fixed position and a z-index? if so i'd try using on the navs div the following css:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew i got it correct by setting the z-index:1

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the example below

the css

```
#my-nav-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

HTML markup

```
<body>
    <div id="my-nav-bar">
        <!-- nav bar content -->
    </div>
    <!-- page content -->
</body>
```

checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/BtjvL/)